# Use enum integer value in a macro to format a string

Tags: c, macros, enums, c-preprocessor

I want to use the value of an enum like that:

```
enum state{
STATE_OK =0,
STATE_KO =1};
```

inside a macro like that:

```
#define DISPLAY_STATE_OK "StateOK="STATE_OK
```

And I want to use it like this:

```
printf(DISPLAY_STATE_OK);
```

To print: StateOK=0

This is a basic example to explain my need. But it does work, any idea to do it? Maybe by replacing enum by a macro #define STATE_OK 0 (not "0" because I need to use it as an integer). But it does work too.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You mean `doesn't work` right?

Comment: is `STATE_OK` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the stringify macro operator `#`.

```
#define STATE_OK (0)

#define STRINGIFY_2(s) STRINGIFY(s)
#define STRINGIFY(s) #s
#define DISPLAY_STATE_OK "StateOK=" STRINGIFY_2(STATE_OK)
```

But this only works if you `#define` the values instead of using an `enum`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
#define DISPLAY_STATE_OK "StateOK="STATE_OK
```

Perhaps:

```
#define DISPLAY_STATE_OK "StateOK=%d", STATE_OK
```

Comment: as long as it can guarantee that it is in a `printf`.